# Laravel Mail not passing public variable to view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass a string into an email in Laravel, but the string is not being shown when viewing the email.

`$recoveryString` being passed into the mail:

```
$recoveryString = str_random(128);

$recoveryString = urlencode($recoveryString);   

RecoveryToken::where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();

$recoveryToken = RecoveryToken::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'recovery_token' => bcrypt($recoveryString),
]);         
        

Mail::to($user)->send(new ForgotEmail($user, $recoveryString));
```

**ForgotEmail.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use App\RecoveryToken;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ForgotEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    
    public $user;
    public $recoveryString;
    


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $recoveryString)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $recoveryString = $recoveryString;
    }
    
    

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('noreply@email.com')
                ->view('emails.forgot');
    }
}
```

In my blade template for the email, `{{ $user->username }}` will retrieve the correct data, but `{{ $recoveryString }}` will just be blank. Why is this happening? I was under the impression that any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo - done this a hundred times myself:

In your constructor, remember to use `$this`:

`$recoveryString = $recoveryString;`  becomes   `$this->recoveryString = $recoveryString;`

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor should have `$this->recoveryString` not `$recoveryString`:

So it should be :

```
     /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $recoveryString)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->recoveryString = $recoveryString;
    }
```